# Determine whether $\int^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{\sin x\cdot \ln x}dx$ is convergence, absolute convergence or divergent.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to determine whether $\int^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{\sin x\cdot \ln x}dx$ is convergence, absolute convergence or divergent.

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin x\cdot \ln x}$, $f(x)< 0$ for $(0,0.5]$.

Therefore I assume I need to work with $-f(x) \ge 0$ in this question.

I'm trying to use the comparing rule without success to solve this.

I thought of using the function $h(x) = \frac{-1}{\ln x}$ which holds $f(x)>g(x)$ in the question's interval, although that didn't get me anywhere.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin{x}<x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$ (draw a picture to see this). So
$$ \frac{1}{\sin{x} \cdot (-\log{x})} >\frac{1}{x \cdot (-\log{x})}, $$
and this has antiderivative $-\log{(-\log{x})}$. This is finite when $x=1/2$ and diverges for $x \to 0$, so the original integral diverges.

Comment: Is this advanced material? I'm not familiar with the antiderivative explanation. We have only learnt the comparing rule, and the theory of Derichlet and the theory of Cauchy's in class

Comment: The original integral is an improper integral because the integrand is unbounded as $x \to 0$, so you have to treat it as $\lim_{a \to 0}\int_a^{1/2}$. I have shown that $\int_a^{1/2} \frac{dx}{-\sin{x}\log{x}}$ is larger than an integral that can be evaluated exactly: $$\int_a^{1/2} \frac{dx}{x(-\log{x})} = \log{(-\log{a})}-\log{(-\log{(1/2)})}, $$ which diverges as $a \to 0$.

Comment: Although those functions are negative. Therefore don't we need to examine the opposites, which are positive and: $\frac{-1}{\sin x \cdot(-\log x)} <\frac{-1}{x\cdot (-\log x)}$? For those functions the comparing rule doesn't neccessairly work

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. $\log{x}$ is negative for $0<x<1$, so $-\log{x}$ is positive. Showing that $f(x) \to -\infty$ is the same as showing that $-f(x) \to +\infty$.